# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException when saving file in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I'm trying to run an existent .NET Core 2.2 console application in Linux. The application reads some data from a third party service and then saves it as a file like this.

```
var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml";
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(savedir,filename), fileData);
```

The value of `savedir` is `/home/ubuntu/saved/` and the directory exists, but I'm still getting this error every time the program reaches that point.

```
Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/.dotnet/tools/12466311-7cd7-4328-8654-2dfaac1f230d.xml'.
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Thanks to the accepted answer it was easy to figure out the problem. The variable savedir is initialized like this:

```
var path = _cfg.GetValue<string>("Path", @"/home/ubuntu/saved");
```

The `Path` value should come from `appsettings.json` but in the initialization code there's this:

```
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
```

It seems that the .NET Framework access to environment variables is not case sensitive, so we ended up having our `Path` parameter with the value of the environment variable `PATH`.

**Update 2**

Thanks to all for your comments and answers!!!

Comment: Does it work if you manually concat the strings?

Comment: Just gave it a try, it  shows the same error message

Comment: What is the result of your Path.Combine call? It should look something like `"/home/ubuntu/saved/f239ae55-45b2-4708-ad1b-10a86121dc2d.xml"`

Comment: *"Just gave it a try, it shows the same error message"* -- that leaves me totally blank :-|

Comment: @yorodm: can you explain what happened? Since I asked you to put the literal string there,  what was the actual error?

Comment: @Stefan sorry I just have access to the fail logs of the app, I changed the code to use `savedir+filename` and the error message was the same.

Comment: ah... I see :-) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it's trying to write to this path:

'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/.dotnet/tools/12466311-7cd7-4328-8654-2dfaac1f230d.xml'.

Which is **not** inside an existing directory path!

It seems like `savedir` is being initialized from the environment variable `$PATH`. You program expects this directory to exist. But it's actually a list of colon-separated directories, not a single directory, in your case. The program seems to expect this to contain a single directory only and doesn't handle this case correctly.

Can you share more details from the application code? How does it initialize `savedir`?

Comment: You are totally right!! Updating my question to show the issue